# Plugging the result of DSolve into the D.E does not yield zero

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am solving the following D.E

```
DSolve[
  (Sin[x1]^2 Sin[x2] ((-1 + l) (3 + l) q1[z] + 3 z q1'[z] - z^2 q1''[z]))/z^5 + 
    (Sin[x1]^2 Sin[x2] ((1 - l) (3 + l) z^2 q1[z] - z^3 q1'[z] + z^4 q1''[z]))/
      (L^2 z^5) == 0, 
  q1[z], z]
```

And the result is given by

```
{{q1[z] -> 
   I^(1 - l) L^(-1 + l) z^(1 - l)
      C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[-(l/2) - 
       1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], -(l/2) + 
       1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], -l, z^2/L^2] + 
    I^(3 + l) L^(-3 - l) z^(3 + l)
      C[2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + l/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], 
      1 + l/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], 2 + l, z^2/L^2]}}
```

So, I set the constants to one, and I feed the solution back in the D.E and setting it to zero. I was expecting a True Statement. This is how I do it.

```
q1[z_] := 
 I^(1 - l) L^(-1 + l) z^(1 - l)
    Hypergeometric2F1[-(l/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], -(l/2) + 
     1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], -l, z^2/L^2] + 
  I^(3 + l) L^(-3 - l) z^(3 + l)
     Hypergeometric2F1[1 + l/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], 
    1 + l/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2], 2 + l, z^2/L^2]
(Sin[x1]^2 Sin[
      x2] ((-1 + l) (3 + l) q1[z] + 3 z Derivative[1][q1][z] - 
       z^2 (q1^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z]))/z^5 + (
    Sin[x1]^2 Sin[
      x2] ((1 - l) (3 + l) z^2 q1[z] - z^3 Derivative[1][q1][z] + 
       z^4 (q1^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z]))/(L^2 z^5) == 0 // 
  Factor // Simplify
```

And the result is

```
(1/(l (2 + l)))
 I^-l L^(-1 - l)
   z^(-1 - l) (2 l (-2 + l + l^2) L^(6 + 2 l)
      Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-l - Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 
      1/2 (-l + Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), -l, z^2/L^2] - 
    2 (-2 + l + l^2) L^(
     4 + 2 l) (z^2 + l (L^2 - z^2)) Hypergeometric2F1[
      1/2 (2 - l - Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 
      1/2 (2 - l + Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 1 - l, z^2/L^2] + 
    z^2 (3 (-2 + l + l^2) L^(
        2 + 2 l) (L^2 - z^2) Hypergeometric2F1[
         1/2 (4 - l - Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 
         1/2 (4 - l + Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 2 - l, z^2/L^2] + 
       I^(2 l) l (3 + l) z^(
        2 l) (2 (2 + l) L^4 Hypergeometric2F1[
            1/2 (2 + l - Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 
            1/2 (2 + l + Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 2 + l, z^2/L^2] + 
          2 L^2 (-(2 + l) L^2 + (3 + l) z^2) Hypergeometric2F1[
            1/2 (4 + l - Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 
            1/2 (4 + l + Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 3 + l, z^2/L^2] + 
          3 z^2 (-L^2 + z^2) Hypergeometric2F1[
            1/2 (6 + l - Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 
            1/2 (6 + l + Sqrt[-2 + 2 l + l^2]), 4 + l, z^2/
            L^2]))) Sin[x1] Sin[x2] == 0
```

And I know that the first term in the solution the DSolve gives is divergent, but this should make no difference. In principle, the result of the DSolve, when plugged in the original D.E should return 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you have special functions in there, you need to use `FullSimplify[]` instead of `Simplify[]`.

Comment: I've tried that as well, and it does not work. More specifically, I've set one of the constants to zero and the other to one to speed up the procedure.

Comment: @J.M.  In my experience, `FullSimplify` is not at all effective at simplifying combinations of hypergeometric functions.  I too cannot obtain zero by substituting the solution into the ODE.

Comment: @Bill  did and I am getting back that C[2] is C[1] times a messed up expression involving hypergeometrics. However, I was expecting that since constants of integration are arbitrary they can be set to any value I like. In any case, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Really appreciated. Chees @Bill !!!